# How to know what happens under the hood of Apache Spark (from the code)?

Tags: git, apache-spark

I want to understand spark by reading code files from apache spark github link.

https://github.com/apache/spark

I have some experience in Scala, but most of my experience has been in PySpark. And I undertand Spark architecture and various optimization techniques too, but I am curious how they are implemented internally. For example what happens when I call repartition() method.
Could anyone from community guide me in how I should go about it.

Comment: You seem to understand Git, so what's the exact question or problem you're having? How is Spark any different than another repo?

Comment: You are right. I was actually looking for others experience, and if anyone has tried it, so thaT it could be better for me to know if there are caveats. And I did try using the latest version of repo, but had lot of issues building it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) to open the [sources of Apache Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark). You can open the sources as a maven or sbt project (just pick the proper build configuration).

Once the above's done, Cmd+Option+o to find a symbol of your interest, e.g. `repartition()`. Use Cmd+b to drill down until you're at the very bottom (of the call chain) and go up (to take a breath...not break!) Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Thanks @jacek you truly are a Spark Evangelist. :)